# Unknown path components. It was working before

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a custom Open Graph action defined in a Facebook app for users that take a picture with our photo application `namespace:take`. It has this capabilities approved:

- User Messages
- Tags
- User Generated Photos
- Explicitly Shared

It has been working for weeks, but today I started returning this error

```
{"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: /namespace:take","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}
```

Is it a problem at Facebook's end? Has something changed that I'm not aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug at Facebook's end, [now solved](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/619299244769134)